How do i remove the thick round borders in SciptUI imagebuttons in After Effects 2025?
Starting with AE2025 my imagebutton buttons started showing up with ugly round borders. Switching to "LegacyUI" doesn't remove them, and I can't find documentation to remove them in code. This issue didn't exist in previous versions of After Effects. Any ideas out there?

